# Is raspberry pi zero w powerful enough for Mysql?

Tags: pi-zero-w, mysql, database

Is raspberry pi zero w powerful enough for hosting a Mysql database?

Comment: Sure.  But probably not *any and all* MySQL databases.  MySQL is depreciated in favour of MariaSQL, BTW.

Comment: A *lot* more information is needed to answer this question.  If you have a single table with perhaps a hundred rows and a few queries per minute, then the answer is yes.  If you have a database of a dozen tables, millions of rows and thousands of queries per second, then the answer is no.  Your own situation is probably somewhere in between.  To help you, we need those details.

Comment: Okay, thank you both, I don't have a raspberry pi yet and was considering it, so there basically was no extra information, even so the answers at least do help me, thanks.